# How can we connect garmin devices to iOS Application using BLE

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, garmin

I am developing an iOS application for Heart rate monitoring, and want to connect a garmin device to my application using Bluetooth.

But I am not able to list down any Garmin device Using Core bluetooth in Swift using (180D Service UUID).

```
  func startUpCentralManager() {
        print("Initializing central manager")
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func discoverDevices() {
        print("discovering devices")
        let services = [CBUUID(string: HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID),CBUUID(string:HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID),CBUUID(string:HRM_DEVICE_BATTERY_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID),CBUUID(string:CALORIE_SERVICE)]
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: nil)
    }

    //MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("checking state")
        switch (central.state) {
        case .poweredOff:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")

        case .poweredOn:
           print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
           blueToothReady = true;

        case .resetting:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting")

        case .unauthorized:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")

        case .unknown:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");

        case .unsupported:
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

        }
        if blueToothReady {
            discoverDevices()
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        let nameOfDeviceFound = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString
        print("\(String(describing: nameOfDeviceFound))")
        print("Discovered Peripheral name : ", peripheral.name ?? String())

           if !Utilities.allPeripheralList.contains(peripheral)
           {
               Utilities.allPeripheralList.add(peripheral)
        }
        let deviceObj = DeviceModel()
        deviceObj.deviceName = peripheral.name ?? String()
        deviceObj.UDID = String(format: "%@",(peripheral.identifier).uuidString)
        self.addingPeripheralToGlobalSearchArray(obj: deviceObj)

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        self.connected = peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.connected ? "YES" : "NO"
        print("Connection Status : %@", self.connected)
        if self.connected == "YES"{

    Utilities.sharedInstance.goToDashboardTabBarScreen(viewController: self)
        }
    }


func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    //        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
}

func addingPeripheralToGlobalSearchArray(obj:DeviceModel){
    var isFound:Bool = false
    for i in 0..<Utilities.allDeviceList.count{
        let deviceObj = Utilities.allDeviceList[i] as! DeviceModel
        if obj.UDID == deviceObj.UDID{
            isFound = true
        }
    }

    if !isFound{
        Utilities.allDeviceList.add(obj)
    }
}
```

Above is the code which I am using to list down BLE devices. I am able to find Mio-Fuse devices using same peace of code but not Garmin devices.

Comment: What do you do to find your device? Do you create CBCentralManager? Do  you call scanForPeripheralsWithServices? Do you get any callbacks after that?

Comment: Yes i am using CBCentralManager, but i am unable to list down any Garmin device.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code, showing what you do to find it? How, for instance, do you tell it's a Garmin device? By exposed services UUIDs? By name?

Comment: @fspirit i have update the question along with the code.

Comment: Try with `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil, options: nil)` If your device doesn't advertise that he has the target services (it may hides it, there is no obligation), you won't find it is you scan for them only.

Comment: @Larme i have tried 
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil, options: nil) 
also but the result is same. :(

Comment: Are you able to find it with LightBlue.app ? Can you give the ref of your Garmin Device?

Comment: No, instead of Garmin app itself, none of the apps are able to search for it.

Comment: @Abhishek , are you sure that any other third party app (not germin app itself) could not find the germin device programmatically for measuring  HR  ? I am going to do a same projects  which will allows multiple types of device like Mio-Fuse, Wahoo, Germin with a single app ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Garmin Standard SDK.  Contact Garmin and register as a developer.  You cannot connect directly using BLE you have to connect via the Garmin SDK API.